# Let's head for vs Let's head to

Tags: meaning, phrases

I wanted to use something different than "Let's go to the party", 
so I tried "Let's **head to** the party", but then, I found other examples with "Let's **head for** the party."
I wonder which one is more correct.

Comment: As a native English speaker, "let's head to the party" sounds more correct if you're going directly there and "let's head for the party" is more correct if you're going to the party but will go somewhere else first. Both sound fine to me though and your meaning will be understood either way.

Comment: I think 'Let's head for' gives the impression you are heading for an event. Eg. Let's head for the graduation. While 'let's head to' gives an impression that you are heading to a place. Ex. Let's head to the house. I'm sure both are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both correct, but with slightly different meanings.

"Head to" connotes that you're confident that you'll actually arrive. A college student might say, "Classes are over, let's head to the bar."

"Head for" connotes that you're going in that direction, but you might get waylaid or you're unsure of the route. A tourist in New York might say, "We're lost; let's head for the Empire State Building so we can get our bearings."